# page_load event in Master and Content Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

Here is the sequence in which events occur when a master page is merged with a content page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

So, my problem is:

I have one login page (not use master page), one master page, and hundreds of content page.

I check login session `Session["loggedInUser"]` in master page (if not logged in, redirect to login page)

So, when I don't log in, if I type the address of one content page, it must check login session in master page and redirect to login page, right? But it has two cases here:

If in content page, I don't use anything related to `Session["loggedInUser"]`, it will redirect to login page, so, it's OK here!

The second case: if I use `Session["loggedInUser"]` to display Username in content page for example:

```
UserInfo loggedInUser = (UserInfo)Session["loggedInUser"];
```

it will return null object here, **because the `page_load` in content page is fired before `page_load` in master page**, so it thows null object instead of redirecting to login page.

I also tried `Page_PreInit` in master page but no help

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["loggedInUser"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you also post the Stack Trace for the exception thrown during the Page_PreInit method above?

Comment: I don't post it because it's nonsense. It's just some thing like `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and point to the code in the content page where I get the `loggedInUser` object

Comment: Man this is a really weird problem.  Wouldn't `Session["loggedInUser"]` get set only in the login page before redirecting or server.transfer back to a content page under the master page?  (Not in master page logic at all)   PS - I usually check auth in Master.Page_Init()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've come up with a solution:

I create a class `BasePage` like this:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["loggedInUser"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

And in the content page, instead of inheriting from `Page`, I change to `BasePage` and it works perfectly

Thanks for all of your support

Nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could check for `Session["loggedInUser"]` in the content Page's `Page_PreRender()` rather than `Page_Load()`or alternatively, do the master page check in the `Page_Init()` rather than `Page_Load()`. We had the same problem and went with the Master page `Page_Init()` option, so that we could still use `Page_Load()` in all the Content pages.

Edit: It's `Page_Init()` *not* `PreInit()`.

Comment: @Hatake It looks like we use `Page_Init()` in the Master, not `Page-PreInit()`, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I hit a very similar problem and moved most of the master's page_load to page_init. Doesn't seem like the right ordering to me, surely master should be first? Too late to change it now I guess.

Comment: @JonB, felt pretty weird to me too!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, when you say you are using the `Session["loggedInUser"]` value, you are then calling `.ToString()` method  or similar to display it?

In which case, you will need to check for a null object before using it. It would be best practice to check for the existance of the object before using any methods on it in any case, so:

```
if (Session["loggedInUser"] != null)
{ ... }
```

**Only if** you are certain that the code will **never** be executed without the Session object being instantiated can you use methods without checking for a null reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx

Comment: Yep, I check null first, then cast the session object into user object

Comment: You check null first, then cast the session object into user object **only if** object != null, correct?

Comment: yes, I did that, but it's not the point here, because the `page_load` event in content page is fired before the `page_load` event in master page, and I don't want to check in content pages, because I have hundreds of pages...

Comment: OK, I get that, which is why I said **Only if** you are certain it will **never** be executed without being prevalidated to exist. You mention that you've already tried using the Master Pages Init event, can you post the stack trace from the exception thrown in this instance?

Comment: I think there's misunderstanding here. When user log in, I save the user object into session. So, when I don't log in and go to the address of content page, it should return to login page (because I check login session in `page_load` function of master page), but it throws null object exception (because I get the user object in `page_load` function of content page, and it's fired before the `page_load` in master page, and I don't check whether it's null or not here, because I don't want to check every page, just master page only, so it must be not null in content page when I get it ;)

Comment: No misunderstanding - I am asking you for the stack trace of the exception in the instance where you have tried putting the Master Page login check in the Master Pages Init event. In response to Jackson Popes answer, you stated that you have already tried it and it didn't work - so please post your stack trace from that attempt, then we can see where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: I've updated more details in my post, I really appreciate your support ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 masterpages(1 for prelogin,2nd for afterlogin),home page is independent,logout page inherits postlogin page) in all postloginpage session chck if sessionnull(xyz)else(redirect loginpage) all this in Page_Init event of afterlogin.master................Successfull

Comment: There are amazing tutorials out there for formatting answer. Please refer those. This will help you a lot in formatting your answer so it can be understandable. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)