# Pass master page control values on content page on page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a dropdowlist on master page and I want to pass the selected value on content pages when a content page loads. My problem is that the value passes only when I change value on the dropdownlist. So when a page load I have to reselect from dropdownlist to capture the value of the dropdown. If I am browsing the content pages the selected value doesnt pass on page load.
My master page code .net:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategories" 
        runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcecategories" DataTextField="CategoryName" 
        DataValueField="CategoryID" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlcategories_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Master page cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {    
      ddlcategories.DataBind();
      ddlcategories.Items.Insert(0, "Uncategorized");
      ddlcategories.Items[0].Value = "0";
      ddlcategories.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Session["lblCategoryID"]);
  }
}
protected void ddlcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["lblCategoryID"] = Convert.ToInt32(ddlcategories.SelectedValue);
}
```

Content page cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    Label10.Text = Convert.ToString(((DropDownList)Master.FindControl("ddlcategories")).SelectedValue);                 
}
```

Comment: What value are you looking for in your DDL on page load? Why use the Session object? You are setting the value of the selected value in the DDL on selected index change so that's what it's only appearing then. I'm not sure why you're doing it like that though.

Comment: Are you declaring the exact type of your Master Page in the markup of your Page?

Comment: Hello yes i am declaring the mastr page on markup. i have set the selected value to maintain the selection when the user browse. I can comment it if confuse you. The session is not important. I am calling the master control not the session. I found this link but the answer doesnt help me a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933929/page-load-event-in-master-and-content-pages?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

Master page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Master page CS:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return ddlcategories.SelectedValue;
    }
    set
    {
        ddlcategories.SelectedValue= value;
    }
}

protected void ddlcategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectedValue = ddlcategories.SelectedValue;
}
```

Content Page markup:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site1.Master" %>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Content page CS.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Master.SelectedValue;
}
```

Note: Values are just to demonstrate, you can use the actual data source values in drop down.

Comment: I am taking this error on content page: System.Web.UI.MasterPage does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue'

Comment: You need to declare MasterType directive on top of content page markup "<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site1.Master" %>" to access master page properties. Are you getting intellisence for Master page's SelectedValue property on content page's code behind?

Comment: I have this declaration MasterPageFile="~/mypath/mymaster.Master"
No i am not taking intellisence

Comment: The intellisence apears is .FindControl and some else. But not SelectedValue

Comment: Have you declared "SelectedValue" property in master page code behind? it works for me. Seems there is soemthing missing in your solution. Is property public? Once you have declared the MasterType directive, build the solution for intellisence to pick up.

Comment: Yes it works, but only if i select from dropdownlist. When the content page accessed initially i dont have results on Label1. Every time i access a content page i have to select from dropdown to see value on Label1. I want on content page load to access the value that already has been assigned on dropdownlist.

Comment: Ok: Check the edited answer, where in content page, value is being accessed on PreRender event rather Load. This should work. The reason is that load of content page fired first when master page hasn't set the values for dropdown, while content page's PreRender fired after master page's Load event. So, the correct page lifecycle event.

Comment: No, at the initialization the Label1 is empty

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I used  session instead of access directly the Selected value and now work. Your solution help me a lot.

Comment: @focus I am glad that you found a working solution. But even the above solution works well, there is definitely something specific in your solution which isn't letting you access drop down's value on first load. I wish I could upload my solution here for you to compare anything missing. But maybe for the future. :)

Comment: Even though this solution seems partially correct, what is the need to set `SelectedValue = ddlcategories.SelectedValue;` if you always return `ddlcategories.SelectedValue;` anyway?

Comment: The reason to get/set dropdown value through a public property is for it to be accessible from outside. In this case from Content Page.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is as the "ContentPage load" occurs before the "MasterPage load" you don't have access to the dropdownlist items.

to solve this issue you can Bind your drobdownlist first in the master page , but not in the "MasterPage load" , you can Bind it in "MasterPage Init" event which occurs before the "ContentPage Init" and "MasterPage Load" events .

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
      ddlcategories.DataBind();
      ddlcategories.Items.Insert(0, "Uncategorized");
      ddlcategories.Items[0].Value = "0";
      ddlcategories.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(Session["lblCategoryID"]);
}
```