# Request.Form value with submit to different page

Tags: asp.net

In my master page inside the form I have an asp.net drop down list (cboStyle) with autopost back set to true. It submits to a different page called StyleRedirect.aspx. In that page's (StyleRedirect.aspx) load event I need to get the selected value of cboStyle and Request.Form("cboStyle") is not working.
how should I do this?

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783165/pass-master-page-control-values-on-content-page-on-page-load

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a property in Master page. This property should be set with the value selected from Dropdown. This value can now be accessed in Content Page using Master object. You can also you event and delegate based solution also for this. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/interacting-with-the-content-page-from-the-master-page-cs

Comment: What if I have 50+ controls I want to capture, is there a better way?

Comment: @Roto : Could you please let me know if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: ToShetty (Won't let me type "At" shetty) The way Ankush describes below would seem to be better, but I am having an issue with it. You can read my issue in the comments

Comment: AtShetty: rereading your initial link, you too are correct, this seems to be the best same way. It still won't let me type AtSignShetty, wtf, nothing is working for me today

Comment: I have been using this or event based solution in initial days of my coding. If you have 40 values which needs to be passed from master page to content, then i think the design should be revisited :)

Comment: those 40 values are spread over a telerik wizard, so the end user sees it as spread over 5 or 6 steps. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/wizard/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your dropdownlist is in master page and the page to which you are submitting is it's child page then you should be able to get the selected value by using

`string selectedValue = ((DropDownList)Master.FindControl("cboStyle")).SelectedValue;`

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have been trying this but it doesn't find the control. But I am actually using a RadDropDownList, it's basically teleriks version of the drop down list. I'd use the Microsoft ddl but it doesn't have a postbackurl option. Let me play with find control again.

Comment: @Roto Normal `<asp:DropDownList>` have the AutopostBack option, it work perfectly and if you want it to redirect somewhere specificaly, you can catch it's event through code behind of the master page

Comment: @Ankush This is working in the sense that I can get the controls, but here is the problem. The ddl is in the master page. On first load the ddl defaults to "Standard" (I have that text marked as Selected). I change that selected text to "SomethingElse", it submits to the new page, but it sends the "Standard" instead of "SomethingElse"

Comment: I guess if the ddl was in the content page I'd be ok. Fortunately most of the controls are in the content page. I weaseled my way around the ddl in the master by using a query string and taking the value from the query string and not the control itself. So Ankusk's answer is correct.